# AsyncTask Later Call

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a problem with AsyncTask.
The `rejectTask()` method is being called earlier than `AddCommentAsync`.
So I have a `nullpointerexception()` in AsyncTask.

If I write the `if` block, `AddCommentAsync` is being called first.
But when`AddCommentAsync` is finished, the `rejectTask()` method isn't called.

```
AddCommentAsync add=null;
add = new AddCommentAsync(activity);
add.execute();
if(add!=null && add.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
ArrayList<String> resultRejected = rejectedTask();
```

Help me someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you should set `resultRejected = rejectedTask();` in the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` method.
And you don't need this line: `if(add!=null && add.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)`.

Please refer to `The four steps` in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: But I can't access some parameters in AsyncTask. Because AsyncTask is in different Class

Comment: Then make the variables accessible.

Comment: Then you can mark my answer as accepted (check the white tickmark, it will become green), so to remove your post from the Unanswered Question Queue.